# Definite integral involving $\exp((-1/x) - x)$

Tags: integration, gamma-distribution

I have a small integration problem. Just for context, this comes out of a bayesian exercise involving gamma functions.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^\alpha e^{-\left( \beta x^{-1} + \gamma x \right)} dx$$

where $\beta>0, \gamma >0$.

I can't get my head around what the right change of variables is. I have tried, naively:

$$y = \beta x^{-1} + \gamma x$$

but I got stuck pretty quickly. Any idea what the best change of variables would be?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure a good MSEer will provide a derivation, which certainly will be instructive, but in the meantime:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\,x^{\alpha - 1}\exp(-px - q/x)\, dx = 2(q/p)^{\alpha/2}K_\alpha(2\sqrt{pq}).
\end{equation}
2.3.16.1, Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev, Integrals and Series, vol 1, Elementary Functions; easier access at [DLMF 10.32.10](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32).